# Scala convert Iterable of Tuples to Array of Just Tuple._2

Tags: scala

Say I have a `Iterable[(Int, String)]`. How do I get an array of just the "values"? That is, how do I convert from `Iterable[(Int, String)] => Array[String]`? The "keys" or "values" do not have to be unique, and that's why I put them in quotation marks.

Answer (score 4):

```
iterable.map(_._2).toArray
```

_._2 : take out the second element of the tuple represented by input variable( _ ) whose name I don't care.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
val iterable: Iterable[(Int, String)] = Iterable((1, "a"), (2, "b"))

val values = iterable.toArray.map(_._2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply `map` the iterable and extract the second element(`tuple._2`),

```
scala> val iterable: Iterable[(Int, String)] = Iterable((100, "Bring me the horizon"), (200, "Porcupine Tree"))
iterable: Iterable[(Int, String)] = List((100,Bring me the horizon), (200,Porcupine Tree))

scala> iterable.map(tuple => tuple._2).toArray
res3: Array[String] = Array(Bring me the horizon, Porcupine Tree)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the already suggested map you might want to build the array as you map from tuple to string instead of converting at some point as it might save an iteration.

```
import scala.collection

val values: Array[String] = iterable.map(_._2)(collection.breakOut)
```